# Using Yelp API to estimate number of businesses in a given city

Tags: python, bigdata, yelp

I'm currently experimenting with the Yelp API, using Python. I'm interested in **estimating the number of businesses present in a city using the Yelp API.**

***Example***

I tried doing this with San Francisco, as follows:

```
#create yelp_api using private keys 
search_results = yelp_api.search_query(location="San Francisco, California")
business_estimate = search_results['total'] #total is the total number of results obtained
```

My reasoning with the above was, in leaving the other fields blank my search would be as broad as possible, i.e. a search of all businesses in San Francisco.

However, between executions of the above script, *business_estimate* fluctuated in the thousands. e.g. 63000, 55000, 81000

***Question***

My question is, **why does business_estimate fluctuate so much?** Also, is there a better method than mine  for estimating the number of businesses in a given city than my method?

For reference, here is the Yelp API documentation: http://www.yelp.ie/developers/documentation/v2/search_api

Comment: If you pull the list `businesses` out of `search_results` and then `count()` the elements, is the number the same as the `total`?

Comment: @Karl I did num=len( search_results['businesses'] ) and I got num=20 consistently (compared to the tens of thousands for business_estimate)

Comment: (That's because by default the Yelp API limits the number of businesses returned (i.e. full JSON string) to 20, by the way. However, I'm not trying to get info on the businesses, rather just the number of businesses existing.

Comment: I didn't see that part of the documentation, I was hoping it would be a quick way of determining if the number you were getting from `total` was accurate :(

Answer (score 0):

If you are really interested in the number of businesses in some area, then it does not seem right to rely on Yelp, which I think focuses on consumer facing businesses and is not very complete. If you want to get the data for free: Have you considered using the Census instead? E.g.:
http://www.census.gov/econ/cbp/overview.htm